# Close all popup windows with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how can I close all popup windows (window popup by javascript) in Javascript?

Example:

1. Open 3 new windows by clicked on a
   button, and using window.open() to
   open all 3 new windows.
2. Clicked on a button and close all 3
   popup windows togather.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var childWindowHandles = new Array();

function openNewWindow(url, params) {
    childWindowHandles[childWindowHandles.length] = window.open(url, '', params);
}    

function closeChildWindows() {
    for (var loop=0; loop<childWindowHandles.length; loop++) 
    {
        if (!childWindowHandles[loop].closed)
        {
            childWindowHandles[loop].close();
        }
    }
}
```

Second result on Google. Closes ALL Windows after storing them in an array.

Here is a more OOP way, if you don't like the global variables. (I'm not 100% sure that it works, just modified the above code.

```
popups = new popups();
function popups()
{
    this.childs = new array();

    this.open = function(url, params)
    {
        this.child.push(window.open(url, '', params)); 
    }

    this.closeAll()
    {
        for(var loop=0; loop<this.childs.length; loop++)
        {
            if (!this.childs[loop].closed)
            {
                this.childs[loop].close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lest we forget about `push`.  It's cleaner and faster (generally): `this.child.push(window.open(url, '', params);`

Comment: I cannot edit the answer, but be careful of adding a ) at the end of :
 this.child.push(window.open(url, '', params)); 
in the OOP solution

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the windows that are opened by storing their handles, then use the [close()](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_close.asp) method on the window handles from the button's click handler.

Personally, I find popup windows to be a really annoying feature when used in a web interface.  If you can possibly avoid them by using DOM-based dialogs, please do.  The [jQuery dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) plugin is very handy for this.